# Приведение к типу str при форматировании строк

Tags: python, строки, форматирование, format

Приводит ли функция `format()` неявно все аргументы к `str`?

Данный код выдает ошибку:

```py
a = 10
print('A: ' + a)
```

А такой нет:

```py
a = 10
print('A: {}'.format(a)
```

Если есть неявное приведение, то не избыточно ли оно, и не лучше ли в самых простейших случаях, когда можно обойтись без `format()`, для конкатенации использовать `+`?

Comment: Можете уточнить суть вопроса? Вас интересует почему в Python не реализовали сложение `str + int` / `int + str` или суть вопроса не в этом?

Comment: @ MaxU, не в этом, а в том, как работает format изнутри и почему ему не нужно передавать аргументах приведенные к str параметры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format` не занимается неявным приведением - он вызывает методы `a.__str__()`, там где его нет вызывает `a.__repr__()` для пустой спецификации `{}`

Answer (score 4):

Метод `.format()` возвращает строку (`str`), и да, его преимущество состоит в том, что он *исходя из типа параметров автоматически конвертирует всё в строку*, также при его самом простом применении (с использованием только `{}` без какой-то спецификации) практически *не может возникнуть ошибка.*

Answer (score 3):

Попробую ответить на вопрос из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108760/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-str-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-python/1108811#comment1912069_1108760):

> как работает format изнутри и почему ему не нужно передавать
>   аргументах приведенные к str параметры?

Предназначение метода `str.format()` в том, чтобы отформатировать переданные ему аргументы в соответствии с указанным форматом и вернуть **строку**.

Также метод `str.format()` позволяет вставлять аргументы *позже*:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT
d  = DT.now()
filename_pat = "filename_{:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.csv"
#...
filename = filename_pat.format(DT.now())
```

[Официальная документация по "мини языку форматирования"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Примеры:

```
# форматирование чисел с плавающей точкой
val = 123456.123456
print("{}".format(val))  # распечатать число как есть - без указания формата
# 123456.123456
print("{:.2f}".format(val)) # показать только 2 знака после десятичной точки
# 123456.12
print("{:,.2f}".format(val)) # показать 2 знака после десятичной точки и разделить на группы по 3 цифры до дес. точки
# 123,456.12
print("{:e}".format(val)) # показать число в экспоненциальном представлении
# 1.234561e+05
```

Кроме того форматировать можно строки и объекты других типов:

```
print("{:~<30}".format("test string"))
# test string~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
print("{:~>30}".format("test string"))
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~test string
print("{:~^30}".format("test string"))
# ~~~~~~~~~test string~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

```
from datetime import datetime as DT
d  = DT.now()
print("Current timestamp: {:%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S.%f}".format(d))
# Current timestamp: 11 April 2020 15:24:44.279490
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя складывать `str`  и `int` .

Используйте так:

```
print('A: ', a)
```

или так:

```
print(f'A: {a}')
```

Comment: Круто, но вопрос был не об этом, можно складывать str и str, выполняет ли функция format скрытое приведение аргументов к str или нет? Ведь она тоже по сути "складывает", или я не прав?

Comment: @NordeN  http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/

Answer (score 2):

Функция `format` **форматирует** строку, подставляя в неё свои аргументы по определённым правилам, используя шаблоны, указанные в строке. Это не сложение, это подстановка аргументов функции в некий шаблон, если так понятнее. Да, по факту там где-то внутри есть конкатенация строк, но не такая примитивная.

В общем случае можно, конечно, использовать конструкцию вида:

`print('строка' + str(некая_численная переменная))`

Но так делать не рекомендуется, считается, что подстановка в шаблон работает несколько оптимальнее, чем простое сложение строк. Ну и она гибче - вы можете указать, сколько хотите иметь знаков после запятой в отображении числа и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, просто интересно вызывается ли неявно приведение внутри этой функции, в статье, что скнул @S. Nick написано "Python f-string accepts objects as well; the objects must have either __str__() or __repr__() magic functions defined.", значит все таки str применяется независимо от типа объекта? Даже если в форматирование передан объект типа str к нему опять применяется str()?

Comment: @NordeN Ну, кстати, это интересный вопрос. Я не знаю кто форматирование по шаблону делает - сам `format` или `__str__` у класса, который он пытается вывести. Но в любом случае если указано какое-то форматирование, то это не простое приведение к `str`, а хитрое.

Comment: @NordeN, функция `format()` и метод `str.format()` всегда возвращают отформатированную __строку__. Т.е. вне зависимости от типа данных поданных на вход `format()` на выходе вы получите строку.